# Custom Extra provider with Component decorator causing infinite loop

Tags: spring-security

I am trying to use a custom Spring Security filter and provider, but for some reason, when providing the wrong credentials, it runs into a finite loop. I was expecting to call the authentication failure handler in UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter and land on an error page, but it is not happening. Below is my snippet of code. I am throwing an InsufficientAuthenticationException exception to mimic the wrong credential flow. If I remove @Component annotation from NotUsedFakeAuthenticationProvider class and create instance of this class where ever it required, then it is not running in an infinite loop. However, I need this provider for other logic. The following is the snippet of code I am using. Any pointers will be helpful, and thank you in advance.

1. Security Configuration

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http, AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) throws Exception {

        final FakeAuthenticationFilter fakeAuthenticationFilter = new FakeAuthenticationFilter();
        fakeAuthenticationFilter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager);

        http    .addFilterBefore(fakeAuthenticationFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) -> authorize
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .formLogin(withDefaults());
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager getAuthenticationManager(HttpSecurity http, FakeAuthenticaitonProvider fakeAuthenticaitonProvider) throws Exception {
        AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder = http.getSharedObject(AuthenticationManagerBuilder.class);
        authenticationManagerBuilder.authenticationProvider(fakeAuthenticaitonProvider);
        return authenticationManagerBuilder.build();
    }
}
```

2. Provider

```
@Component
public class FakeAuthenticaitonProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {
    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        throw new InsufficientAuthenticationException("user name passwrod wrong");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
        return FakeAuthenticationToken.class.isAssignableFrom(authentication);
    }
}
```

3. Custom Filter

```
public class FakeAuthenticationFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {

@Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws AuthenticationException {
        if (!request.getMethod().equals("POST")) {
            throw new AuthenticationServiceException("Authentication method not supported: " + request.getMethod());
        } else {
            String username = this.obtainUsername(request);
            username = username != null ? username.trim() : "";
            String password = this.obtainPassword(request);
            password = password != null ? password : "";
            FakeAuthenticationToken authRequest = new FakeAuthenticationToken(username, password);
            this.setDetails(request, authRequest);
            return this.getAuthenticationManager().authenticate(authRequest);
        }
    }
}
```

4. Token

```
public class FakeAuthenticationToken extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken {
    public FakeAuthenticationToken(Object principal, Object credentials) {
        super(principal, credentials);
    }
}
```

5. Extra Provider for other purpose

```
@Component
public class NotUsedFakeAuthenticaitonProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {
    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        throw new InsufficientAuthenticationException("Dummy");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
        return FakeAuthenticationToken2.class.isAssignableFrom(authentication);
    }
}
```

```
public class FakeAuthenticationToken2 extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken {
    public FakeAuthenticationToken2(Object principal, Object credentials) {
        super(principal, credentials);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you writing custom security as it is bad practice

Comment: @Toerktumlare I have to take some custom decision based on some criteria and also my FakeAuthenticationFilter is extending from UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter which I believe gives all out of feature.